# iReport "org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile" error in hibernate connection testing

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to make a hibernate connection to create some reports, but every time I press **Test** it appears an error window that says **org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile**, only that.

My classpath already has a jar of my project and the only place where I have the library from the error is inside an entity on the project.

If switch to another's project jar the connection is successful.

I'm using iReport 5.0.4 and Spring 2.9.1.

I'll appreciate any idea of what could be wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: `but every time I press Test` - Where you press this button?

Comment: @AlexK when I configure the hibernate connection. You have 3 buttons: Test, Save and Cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what was the problem, so I commented all references to the library and generated the jar that way.
I did it only because there's no related data to the things I commented.